# Wrong URL at mouseover in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, helper

I have a web application ASP.Net MVC 4 in VS 2017.
I made a custom helper (a link).
I debugged and the custom helper outputs the correct link:
Like this:

```
<a href="MyController/MyAction?Id=3" id="MyLink">Click here</a>
```

Also in the view source code of the browser, it shows ok.

But when I mouse over the link the URL shows like this:

```
http://localhost:1234/MyController/MyController/MyAction?Id=3
```

That is, **the Controller part appears duplicated**, and of course
when I click, it doesn't go to the right destination.

Any ideas, what happened?

Comment: You made a custom link helper. It causes an error. You need help with that error. Then please read [ask] and include the actual code of your custom link helper.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be outputting a relative URL.  Relative URLs are always.. ahem.. relative to the currently displayed URL.

You probably want to place a slash in front of your relative URL to make it relative to the root of the site, instead of relative to the current URL.

```
<a href="/MyController/MyAction?Id=3" id="MyLink">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Which works fine, until you deploy your application as an application inside a website, say, `FooApp`. Then links go to `http://localhost/MyController` instead of `http://localhost/FooApp/MyController`. There's a reason MVC comes with link helpers, they do their job well. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You are right, Sam Axe. I added a slash and it shows ok,

Comment: Yes I use the helpers that comes with MVC, but this time I needed a custom helper because i needed some logic to display different contents and tags (depending on a condition) inside the link. I didn't include in my answer for simplicity reasons.

Comment: @PaulZ.: good.  Now instead of whatever path voodoo you are using now, try using `UrlHelper.Action` to generate your url.

Answer (score 0):

In the above Url.Action method, the first parameter is the name of the action method and the second parameter is the name of the controller in which this action method exists.

[Url.Action in ASP.NET MVC](http://techfunda.com/howto/251/get-url-of-action-method)

```
 <a href="@(Url.Action("MyAction","MyController",new{Id=3}))" id="MyLink">Click here</a>
```